# OneDrive SDK UWA "AuthenticationFailure"

Tags: authentication, win-universal-app, onedrive

I'm building a W10 Universal app and I would like to know who is logged in to Windows so I can associate their data on my server with something that uniquely identifies the user w/o requiring a separate login.
OneDrive SDK is supposed to make this simple and easy.
So, I registered my app with OneDrive, used nuget to install the packages, downloaded the samples and wrote the following code.....

```
var scopes = new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.offline_access", "onedrive.readonly" };
var client = OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(scopes);
try {
    await client.AuthenticateAsync();
}
catch {
    blahlblahblah;
}
```

This doesn't throw an exception, but, after AuthenticateAsync executes, the client's IsAuthenticated property is still false and the ServiceInfo's UserId is null.
So, I tried this next:

```
var client = OneDriveClient.GetMicrosoftAccountClient(
            this.Resources["AppID"].ToString(),
            this.Resources["ReturnUri"].ToString(),
            scopes
        );
```

where the AppID and ReturnUri match the Client ID and Redirect URL that are registered with the app.

This actually throws a OneDrive.Sdk.Error with a message of "Failed to retrieve a valid authentication token for the user."

So, I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.  I'm at a total loss.  I pulled up Fiddler to see what was being sent back & forth and nothing shows up.  There's just not enough information for me to figure this out.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Did you associate your app with the Store? You can do this by right clicking on the csproj and selecting Store -> Associate App with the Store.

Comment: Thanks ginach.  I DID associate the app to the Store.  And, just to make sure, I just did it again.  I still get the same results.

I have another app (W8 not Universal) that's using the Live SDK for the exact same purpose and it authenticates my Windows account just fine, so I don't think it's a problem with my account.

Comment: Where are you doing the client initialization? Is it during or after App.OnLaunched() or are you doing the call in the App constructor?

Comment: It's during the App.OnLaunched() event.  Is that the wrong place to do this?

Comment: No, that's a good place for it. If done in the App constructor auth fails because the app context isn't completely initialzed yet. It also fails before making network calls. This is the first I've seen where AuthenticateAsync after GetUniversalClient silently fails with nothing. Could you try OneDriveClientExtensions.GetAuthenticatedClientUsingWebAuthenticationBroker(clientId, scopes) and see what happens?

Comment: Switching to GetAuthenticatedClientUsingWebAuthenticationBroker brings up a white screen that states "We're unable to complete your request" "Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems.  Please try again later."

Comment: Which client ID are you using? You'll want to use the client ID from the Microsoft account developer center (it will look something like this: 000000004C16944D). The error above can happen when you're using a client ID other than the one associated with the app in the Windows Store. You can find that client ID at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=193157.

Comment: I clicked on the link you provided and noticed there were 2 instances of the app registered.  So, I deleted the 1 that didn't have "View at the Windows Store" and changed my ClientID to match the other one.  GetUniversalClient still returns false from IsAuthenticated after calling AuthenticateAsync, but now GetAuthenticatedClientUsingWebAuthenticationBroker works properly.

Comment: It looks like there's a bug with how IsAuthenticated is being calculated. It's taking expiration into account but OnlineIdAuthenticator isn't returning that value. Since expiration is set to the default of DateTimeOffset IsAuthenticated is showing false. Can you check the value of client.AuthenticationProvider.CurrentAccountSession and see if it's set and has an AccessToken through the OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(scopes) flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, ginach's workaround for the problem seems to be the solution until the bug is fixed.  So, to sum it up....

Don't use the IsAuthenticated property of the UniversalClient.  Instead, check the client's AuthenticationProvider's CurrentAccountSession to see if it has a value and an AccessToken.

```
var client = OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(scopes);
await client.AuthenticateAsync();
if (client.AuthenticationProvider.CurrentAccountSession != null && client.AuthenticationProvider.CurrentAccountSession.AccessToken != null) {
    blahblahblahblahblah
}
```

This seems to do the trick.